# Fix to get my wishes?

Tags: ios

I have problems in myself when I drive cars  I forget to slowly in some way have cameras  speed in high ways so I thinked if possible to make  IOS  APP to fixing these problems I explain my thing in image but I can't convert to coding by this step ?

1-After to  speed camera  100 Miter  Alerts me app( (there are camera speeds pleas slow down your speed.))

2- just post code i have basic programming languages in swift.

Comment: Firstly, just drive the speed limit. Secondly, demanding code isn't going to help and spamming comments isn't either.

Comment: I asked this question to help me some one ☝️

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got you wright, so please correct me if I'm wrong. 
You want an iOS app that tells you if there is a speed camera on the road you're driving, right?

So you have some possibilities to achieve that:

- you can have a look at the app store. There are lot of such apps (e.g. TomTom) (easiest way)
- if you want to build your own app you can make a use of the navigation sdk provided by mapbox: https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-navigation-sdk/ (some programming skills needed)
- Build your own app from scratch (much work and advanced programming skills)

If you want to build your app by mapbox or on your own you'll need the GPS-locations of speed cameras like provided here: https://www.scdb.info/

Comment: Yes you're right bro i want make an ios app but my town have static camera  speed in road i want alret my app after 100 mitre